# GPRS connection in Wince6.0 using Dialup network

Tags: windows-ce

Am trying to connect GPRS using Serial Modem in Wince6.0 , while dialing its showing Port opened and device connected but there is no IP address available.Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting with GPRS you usually need to dial a particular phone number like *99***1# and you may also need to specify the IP gateway or other network specific parameters using additional AT commands.